# How can I take the datas of a growing list in python3

Tags: python-3.x, list

There is my list :

```
fieldNames = ["Your Firstname","Year of birth", "Month of birth", "Day of   Birth"]
birthValues = []
birthValues = multenterbox(msg, title, fieldNames)
yourName = birthValues[0]
yearBirth = birthValues[1]
 monthBirth = birthValues[2]
dayBirth = birthValues[3]
```

I can find the lenght of the list with :
  len(fieldNames)

My problem is that I keep add values in the list.  So I need something that can take the next values automatcly [4] [5] [6] etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean you wan a loop, like this ?

```
fieldNames = ["Your Firstname","Year of birth", "Month of birth", "Day of   Birth"]
birthValues = multenterbox(msg, title, fieldNames)
mapping = dict()
for i in range(len(fieldNames)):
    mapping[fieldNames[i]] = birthValues[i]
```

And you can access birthname with `mapping["Your Firstname"]`.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was searching.